# Story where words are banned

Tags: story-identification, morality

I am trying to find a story I read many years ago wherein, some time in the future, students wanted to put on a Shakespearean play but the censors found so many words had been banned and for disparate reasons, that the only words the students could use were "and" and "the".  Does this sound familiar to anyone??

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't ring a bell, offhand, but it reminds me of how George Orwell, in some material at the end of his novel *1984,* told us that the plan behind "Newspeak" was to have future generations raised speaking a simplified version of the English language in which it would not be possible to think, much less express, various types of subversive thoughts which would challenge the current system of government.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a story very like this -- Connie Willis's "Ado."  It's not students but a teacher who picks *Hamlet* to teach because it has the fewest issues, and by the time they are done censoring out everything that's objected to, they are left with a few sentences.

Comment: You can read the storyu at the Internet Archive https://archive.org/stream/Asimovs_v12n01_1988-01#page/n79/mode/1up

Comment: I have been searching for this story for a long time and you pointed me right to it.  Thank you !!